How to find cause of many IllegalMonitorStateException's in ReentrantLock crippling the JVM?
We have a busy Spring Boot app on Java 11 that runs for anything from a few minutes to a few hours and then spams the logs with these:
2024-04-08 12:54:08.079 Exception in thread "redisson-3-11" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
2024-04-08 12:54:08.079 at java.base/java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$Sync.tryRelease(ReentrantLock.java:149)
2024-04-08 12:54:08.079 at java.base/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.release(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1302)
2024-04-08 12:54:08.079 at java.base/java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock.unlock(ReentrantLock.java:439)
2024-04-08 12:54:08.079 at java.base/java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:440)
2024-04-08 12:54:08.079 at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1054)
2024-04-08 12:54:08.079 at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1114)
2024-04-08 12:54:08.079 at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
2024-04-08 12:54:08.079 at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
2024-04-08 12:54:08.079 at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
    

From many different threads all with the same stack trace:
2024-04-08 12:54:08.079 Exception in thread "redisson-3-11" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
2024-04-08 12:54:54.680 Exception in thread "redisson-3-12" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
2024-04-08 12:54:58.202 Exception in thread "http-nio-8209-exec-11" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
2024-04-08 12:55:51.790 Exception in thread "http-nio-8209-exec-89" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
.. many more ..
2024-04-08 13:16:46.576 Exception in thread "redisson-3-15" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
2024-04-08 13:23:14.380 Exception in thread "web-6" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
2024-04-08 13:23:22.065 Exception in thread "HikariPool-1 connection adder" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
2024-04-08 13:23:34.204 Exception in thread "web-8" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException

The first thread to log varies. It seems anything using a ReentrantLock is broken from this point onwards. It doesn't seem to be memory related (bumped up heap, still happens, lots of free memory, no OOM exception). We have upgraded to the latest Java 11 image (eclipse-temurin:11.0.22_7-jdk-jammy).
We have added a hack to detect this condition (@Scheduled task that stops running) and exit the JVM as a workaround but that's not ideal. Anyone have any ideas?
Thanks

From the thread names I conclude that you are using Redis. Which version of the redisson-library do you use? For example the bug report https://github.com/redisson/redisson/issues/4871 mentions similar problems.

The error happens in all threads using a LinkedBlockingQueue and it is not always a redisson thread that shows up first. I will try upgrade Redisson though and see if that helps.

That linked bug report is about a Redisson specific lock implementation. The problem in this question is about the standard ReentrantLock, within the well tested standard class LinkedBlockingQueue. I don’t think that they are related.

We finally figured out what was going on. Our app had an (accidentally) unsecured monitoring endpoint that listed all threads with links to interrupt and terminate each. A web crawler found the endpoint and was following the links and randomly interrupting and/or killing threads!

I found several similar bug reports, though none of them specifically for the LinkedBlockingQueue. But the following comment is a perfect fit for the code structure of the take method:

But ReentrantLock is not hardened sufficiently against OOME and that can lead to mysterious IllegalMonitorStateException when doing an unlock in a finally block that was wrapping an await() call that threw OOME trying to reacquire the lock after the wait…

This problem has not been solved yet. But if the trigger truly is an OutOfMemoryError, you have to address the problem of insufficient memory anyway. Solving it will remove those spurious exceptions as a byproduct.

It's more often to happen due to a stack overflow (JDK-8318888).

@BenManes that bug report is about the lock still being in a locked state, whereas the OP’s case is about an IllegalMonitorStateException which indicates that it is not locked (when it should be). Besides that, the question’s stack trace has a depth of nine, which makes a stack overflow an unlikely cause. Further, the problem appearing in lots of threads at the same time also indicates a global problem, like being out of memory, rather than a thread local problem like a stack overflow.
